# How to transfer file ownership across gsuite domains - whilst retaining file id's

Tags: google-workspace

My former school is planning to move from Gsuite to Office 365. Gsuite will be closed down.
As a former employee I have lost my admin privileges but for the moment I still have access to my previous Gsuite Edu account.

There are folders in my former Gsuite Edu account that are shared to my personal account and moved into it's My Drive.

I'm aware of using Google Takeout to retain a copy of my files - but that method would create files with different document id's and lots of my files are used within website links, query statements in sheets and data studio reports etc.

To avoid the problems of document Id's being lost when the Gsuite domain is closed I would like to transfer ownership of some of my files rather than just gain a copy of them.

The current domain admin has kindly agreed to meet with me so we can effect the transfer, but I am concerned about how to transfer ownership of files to another domain.

The new domain admin is not knowledgeable about Gsuite administration, I will need to guide them through the process (if I can find out myself if and how it can be achieved).

Comment: I think this may not be possible with GSuite as Google will only allow transfer of ownership for the document to another user on the **same domain**.

Comment: You may well be right, but I was hoping others might no differently. I’ve read that shared drives can be used for this, but I’ve no first hand knowledge.